# Reportportal 4.0.0 getting error "ItemID cannot be null"

Tags: testng, reportportal

I upgraded to latest version (4.0.0) of reportportal today and when I try to run the test, I get  the following error.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ItemID should not be null
at rp.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:122)
at com.epam.reportportal.service.LaunchImpl.finishTestItem(LaunchImpl.java:206)
at com.epam.reportportal.testng.TestNGService.finishTestMethod(TestNGService.java:156)
at com.epam.reportportal.testng.BaseTestNGListener.onTestFailure(BaseTestNGListener.java:98)
```

The other error I am getting is :
     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
     com.epam.ta.reportportal.ws.model.StartTestItemRQ.setRetry(Z)V
    at

com.epam.reportportal.testng.TestNGService.buildStartStepRq(TestNGService.java:280)
    at com.epam.reportportal.testng.TestNGService.startTestMethod(TestNGService.java:140)
        at

com.epam.reportportal.testng.TestNGService.finishTestMethod(TestNGService.java:152)
        at com.epam.reportportal.testng.BaseTestNGListener.onTestSkipped(BaseTestNGListener.java:103)

```
customListener = new CustomTestListener();
ReportPortalTestNGListener listener = newReportPortalTestNGListener();
TestNG myTestNG = new TestNG();
myTestNG.addListener((ITestNGListener) customReporter);
myTestNG.addListener((ITestNGListener) customListener);
myTestNG.addListener((Object)listener);
```

I am using the following versions

```
compile 'com.epam.reportportal:agent-java-testng:4.0.0'
compile 'com.epam.reportportal:logger-java-logback:4.0.0'
compile 'com.epam.reportportal:logger-java-log4j:4.0.0'
```

Comment: Found the problem . Can the contributors please fix this.
agent-java-testNG is built with commons-model:4.0.0'

However, logger-java-logback is built with commons-model:4.0.3'.

The StartTestItemRQ.setRetry(with a param) does not exist in commons-model:4.0.3 which is the cause for error when I use all three imports.


Error:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.epam.ta.reportportal.ws.model.StartTestItemRQ.setRetry(Z)V at

So, either agent-java-testng needs to be built with common-model-4.0.3.,
OR 
Rollback logback and log4j to use common-model-4.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue has been fixed in latest agent versions (4.0.x). Please, make sure you are up to date for all dependencies. Please, submit issue on github in case you still have problem.